# Android application crashes with SIGSEGV on Lollipop while swipe between tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on an android application for some time, with min-max api levels 14 to 19 without any issue. I have compiled the application with target api 21 and I'm getting a SIGSEGV without much information to debug it.

I have an activity that sets up an ActionBar and a view pager with  a fragmentPagerAdapter. When I swipe between the different tabs, the error comes up but always with the same fault address 0x5c.

This is what i get:

```
04-06 16:55:06.803: D/MyLog - MeterActivity(30758): onTabSelected
04-06 16:55:07.374: A/libc(30758): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x5c in tid 30758 (mymeter)
04-06 16:55:07.374: W/libc(30758): Security Level: (1), Debug inforamtion is controlled by the DUMPABLE flag.
04-06 16:55:08.595: W/asset(32334): Copying FileAsset 0xb8c100d0 (zip:/data/app/com.examples.apps.mymeter-1/base.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 368912 to make it aligned.
04-06 16:55:08.615: D/MyLog - ApplicationManager(32334): onCreate
04-06 16:55:08.886: D/Atlas(32334): Validating map...  
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: TEST SBA AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.006.014 + c1105519 ()
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): Build Date: 01/23/15 Fri
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): Local Branch: 
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): Remote Branch:     refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.006.014
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): Local Patches: NONE
04-06 16:55:08.916: I/Adreno-EGL(32334): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
```

I have added the google play service as I'm using the AdMob but I'm not using the Atlas that is logged in the debug logs.

Could you please give me some advice on how to proceed and solve the issue? How can i find out what causes the problem?

Thank you,
L.